# Python RegEx that matches 2 string fields

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to create a RegEx that will help me with my process. I have to see if 2 fields that contain text match or not, e.g

```
fA="John Cohen" and fB="Jackie Cohen SRL"
```

First: I want to see how many words there are ==> 2 in fA and 3 in fB. Sometimes fA or fB have only 1 word and I need to see if fA = fB

Second: I need to see if fA is included in fB or if is the same, and what is different?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for what you want to accomplish. What have you tried until now, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Hi, I am new to Python. Did RegEx in VBA, not in Python. Therefore i need help, as is a new language for me. Currently working with Selenium, Django and Bootstrap. They are not the right module to do that....thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regex won't be the right tool for what you want.

You can start by splitting your strings (which gives you lists of words), and making [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) from them.

Then, you can easily and quickly get the common elements, differences and so on, see the documentation for all possible operations.

Some of the things you want could be accomplished this way:

```
fA="John Cohen" 
fB="Jackie Cohen SRL"

set_A = set(fA.split())
# {'Cohen', 'John'}
set_B = set(fB.split())
# {'Cohen', 'Jackie', 'SRL'}

if len(set_A) == 1 and set_A == set_B:
    print("Both strings are {}".format(fA))

# set_A included in (or equal to) set_B?
if set_A <= set_B:
    print("{} included in {}".format(set_A, set_B))

# common elements
print(set_A & set_B)
# {'Cohen'}

# in set_B but not in set_A
print(set_B - set_A)
# {'SRL', 'Jackie'}

# in set_A or set_B, but not in both
print(set_A ^ set_B)
# {'John', 'SRL', 'Jackie'}
```

You could print the elements of a set like this:

```
print('/'.join(set_A ^ set_B))
# John/SRL/Jackie
```

but note that the order will be random, as sets are not ordered.
You could also turn the sets into lists with `list(set_A)` and sort them if you need.

Comment: Thierry, you really rock! thank you! Is this normal python code, or i have to install some other modules like re etc.

Comment: Nothing to import, sets are a standard data structure.